# Move Eclipse installation to a folder outside of the user profile?

Tags: java, windows, eclipse

Upon installing the Eclipse IDE, a number of hidden folders are created (for example `.p2` and `.eclipse`) under the user profile on the C: drive.

The problem I am having is that our user profiles at work are limited in size, and these folders exceed the limited amount.

If you attempt to move a folder to another location such as an external drive or network drive, Eclipse fails to start. I have tried searching for a config file whereby I could reappoint the file location, but have been unable to find anything of the sort. I presume it is set on initial installation.

So what I'm asking is - is it possible to move the location of `.p2` (and potentially other hidden Eclipse installation folders), or is Eclipse dependant upon being installed into the user profile?

Many Thanks,
Dan.

Comment: *.p2 is not existing and all my *.eclipse folders are 60 byte. i have no clue what your problem could be

Comment: Have you tried specifying the user.home property to point to the directory on commandline?

Comment: @XtremeBaumer Unfortunately because .p2 is the bundle pool, as soon as you download any package such as Maven / JUnit etc, the p2 folder quickly fills up.

Comment: i am using maven and p2 still does not exist

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The .p2 directory is where the Oomph installer puts everything it installs.

You can download 'package' installs which have a lot of pre-installed things which will be in the install directory wherever you put it.

Package installs are at https://www.eclipse.org/downloads/eclipse-packages/

For completeness I will also mention that there are also some package installs at http://download.eclipse.org/eclipse/downloads/ These are very minimal builds of Eclipse and don't include the Oomph installer at all. Everything you install using these builds will be put in the install directory.

Comment: Interesting, so what you are suggesting then is that my "issue" most likely lays with the Oomph installer and that this could be overcome by using a lightweight build of Eclipse? I will investigate and let you know how I get on. Thank you for your help.

Comment: It is just where the Oomph installer puts things. Some of the package builds have just as much stuff pre-installed but everything is in the install directory rather than the .p2 directory.